# Delphi : application to download the files using the authentication

Tags: delphi, cookies

I want to create a tool to download files from the website in the following order :

1. Users enter 'username ' and ' password '
2. Cookies are stored
3. Keep Session Cookies
4. Download the file

Until now, to perform the above tasks , I use ' wget ' with the script :

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" --post-data="username=%id%&password=%password%&sublogin=Login" --save-cookies="cookies\cookies.txt" --keep-session-cookies http://%app%/login/login/loging_simpel
```

how do I do that with Delphi?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244255/how-to-download-a-file-over-https-using-indy-10-and-openssl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Indy `TIdHTTP` component for that:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1';
PostData := TStringList.Create;
try
  PostData.Add('username='+Username);
  PostData.Add('password='+Password);
  PostData.Add('sublogin=Login');
  IdHTTP1.Post('http://'+app+'/login/login/loging_simpel', PostData);
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;
```